# AMQP - connection timed out

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I receive an error, when trying to receive answer from RabbitMQ.

```
2015-07-03 09:31:12 [10.1.101.55][-][-][error][PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException] exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException' with message 'The connection timed out after 30 sec while awaiting incoming data' in /opt/www/site.ll/vendor/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php:130
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/www/site.ll/vendor/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(147): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->wait()
#1 /opt/www/site.ll/vendor/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(105): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
#2 /opt/www/site.ll/vendor/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(528): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
#3 /opt/www/site.ll/vendor/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(568): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(30)
#4 /opt/www/site.ll/vendor/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel(1, 30)
#5 /opt/www/site.ll/vendor/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(332): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame(30)
```

When I trying to receive answer from my local pc it works, but on production server - not.

Why, and how I can fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: check if the ports for the MQ channels are not blocked or if the MQ service itself is running?

Comment: It's running. AMQP receive my message, and process starting, but I dont receive answer. AMQP called callback function 42 times but there no my request. Then I receive exception.

Comment: On local PC I receive answer in 4 seconds.

Comment: If you can connect locally but not to remote servers, perhaps are you using the `guest` user account? See https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: No, it's remote server.

Comment: Any solution did we found here ?

Comment: I'm getting this on Ubuntu... `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException: The connection timed out after 3 sec while awaiting incoming data in /home/website/PhpstormProjects/project/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php:132`

Comment: For my case the timeout was due to me trying to connect to the wrong port.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the correct port is set. Default is 5672 (not 15672 which is web interface).

Comment: This was the answer in my case.

Comment: What's the difference ?

Comment: The web interface is where you can login on RabbitMQ admin panel from browser, like: your-site.com: 15672. That's different from the port that the application needs to connect to the message server itself to publish, consume, etc. For this purpose port 5672 should be configured.

Answer (score 2):

The deafult timeouts for `Connection`, `Read` and `Write` is 3s. In the development, your requests process too faster than production, so you can't see this error message in the development.

If you need a greater timeout (as me), you can set it when you create an instance of `AMQPStreamConnection`:

```php
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
        'localhost',
        5672,
        'guest',
        'guest',
        '/',
        false,
        'AMQPLAIN',
        null,
        'en_US',
        30, //Connection Timeout
        30 // Read/Write Timeout
);
```

The above code set the `Connection`, `Read` and `Write` timeouts to 30s which is reasonable in my case.