# The connection timed out after 30 sec while awaiting incoming data

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rabbitmq

```bash
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException' with message 'The connection timed out after 30 sec while awaiting incoming data' in /var/code/www/thebank.vn/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php:141
Stack trace:
#0 /var/code/www/thebank.vn/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(163): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->wait()
#1 /var/code/www/thebank.vn/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(106): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
#2 /var/code/www/thebank.vn/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(566): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
#3 /var/code/www/thebank.vn/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(623): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(30)
#4 /var/code/www/thebank.vn/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(234): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel(0, 30)
#5 /var/code/www/thebank.vn in /var/code/www/thebank.vn/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php on line 141
```

When I trying to receive answer from my local pc it works, but on production server - not.

Why, and how I can fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMQP - connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202756/amqp-connection-timed-out)